# Magento Import via AvS_FastSimpleImport: how to use?

Tags: magento, import

I am familiar with php and oop, but not with magento.
The Magento ImportWrapper "AvS_FastSimpleImport" offers no entrypoint to run a import prozedure.

like: 
1.) select .php-File (which contains Arrays) 
2.) click "Check Php-Import-Array-File"
3.) Do the import.

Therefore i have to create a extra Module which implements AvS_FastSimpleImport and run the new Module from AdminInterface?
I think this Solution is crap.

So, my Question is: how can i say "Hello World" with AvS_FastSimpleImport.

Thx!

Comment: Calling a module crap without having read the documentation which lists such an example is crap.

Answer (score 1):

The code is designed to be included into your own module. It can be called from a shell script as well, see this [example](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/blob/master/test.php).